# Multithreading in c# but variables change too fast

Tags: c#, multithreading

I have a class that executes my function but the variable changes too fast for me to even append my file. I need the speed but I need the functionality in my multithreading. Here's what's in my program.cs that's really the main key in multithreading.

```
        process process = new process();
        Thread[] threads = new Thread[15];
        static int refInt = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < threads.Count(); i++)
        {
            threads[i] = new Thread(process.checkCookies);
        }

        foreach (Thread threadStart in threads)
        {
            threadStart.Start();
        }
```

That's my program.cs and here's my process library.

```
    public void checkCookies()
    {
        try
        {
            while (Interlocked.Increment(ref refInt) < cookies.Count)
            {
                try
                {
                    string data = functions.cookieToUserId(cookies[refInt]);
                    if (data == "The cookie is incorrect.")
                    {
                        ConsoleWrite("\nThe cookie is invalid.", ConsoleColor.DarkRed);
                        continue;
                    }
                    string cookiesValue = functions.getRobux(cookies[refInt]);
                    if (cookiesValue == "Invalid cookie.")
                    {
                        ConsoleWrite("\nThe cookie is invalid.", ConsoleColor.DarkRed);
                        continue;
                    }
                    else if (Convert.ToInt32(cookiesValue) < 5)
                    {
                        ConsoleWrite(string.Format("\nThe account has less than 5 currency. [{0}]", data), ConsoleColor.DarkRed);
                        continue;
                    }
                    else if (Convert.ToInt32(cookiesValue) > 5)
                    {
                        ConsoleWrite(string.Format("\nThe account has {0} currency. [{1}]", cookiesValue, data), ConsoleColor.DarkGreen);
                        functions.appendFile("config/checkedCookies.txt", cookies[refInt]);
                        continue;
                    }
                }
                catch
                {
                    //exception
                }
            }
        }
        catch
        {
            //exception
        }
    }
```

My issue is that whenever there is a cookie with a currency integer greater than 5, when it appendsFile which is basically this function here.

```
    public string appendFile(string file, string content)
    {
        try
        {
            using (StreamWriter writeStream = File.AppendText(file))
            {
                writeStream.WriteLine(content);
                return "Appended the text successfully!";
            }
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            return "Error appending the text.";
        }
    }
```

The refInt changes due to another thread running it. So if refInt is equal to 4, then after it goes through all the else if statements. The refInt changes to 20-25 because of the other threads running the code and changing the global variable so whenever I append text, it appends the wrong cookie. What are some methods to make it so the global variable doesn't get changed too fast, by the way. I need the speed to be as fast as that.

Comment: Make your life easier by using a [Parallel.ForEach Loop](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/parallel-programming/how-to-write-a-simple-parallel-foreach-loop) on your cookies list.

Comment: But I need it to have no duplicates what so ever hence why I'm passing a reference

Comment: Interlocked.Increment() returns the value you need, not refInt.  Store it in a local variable.

Comment: Your `Interlocked.Increment` only safely increments the refInt at that point. But `cookies[refInt]` could be reading a different value(not locked scope). You  could use  a `lock{...}` scope around the body

Comment: The world has gone mad adding `catch (Exception)` and `catch` to code like it is something you should do. You really shouldn't. You should only ever catch specific exceptions that you can meaningfully handle.

Comment: What is it that your code is trying to do? And why do you think throwing 15 threads at it will help?

Answer (score -1):

i dont know if its helps or kills ur multithreading idee but did u ever think about mutex lock?
https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/1d42da/threading-with-mutex/

Comment: Please don't link to external sites as an answer. Only use links to support content already in your answer.